# Android - app logging screen with picture (probably layout issue)

Tags: android

I am building design for business app and I am stuck at layout on opening screen. Here is the source code. Here is the screen my screen [looks like now](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/3485/aaamu.jpg), and [here](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/1995/aaakopie.jpg) I want it to look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="40dip"
    >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/background"
            >
                <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/test_image"
                   android:src="@drawable/user_lock"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/background">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:password="true"
                    />
         <TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <TableRow> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
        </TableRow> 

        </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am doing my best, but don't know why are you reacting off topic.

Comment: Your table layout should be outside your second LinearLayout. Because second LinearLayout is constrained in width to be to the right of the image.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it, but then buttons never shows up :(

Comment: that's why it is a comment. Not an answer? It does help you get answer though, so it's a good tip that @dave.c gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is overcomplicated (which affects performance and readability) and poorly formatted. Consider using the following variant:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:padding="40dip"
>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/test_image"
    android:src="@drawable/user_lock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/test_image"
/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:password="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/test_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/test_image"
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/test_image"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (just close the LinearLayout where you have the 2 EditText)

```
(....) <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/background">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:maxLines="1"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:password="true"
            />
 </LinearLayout>

 <TableLayout (...)
```

(...)